# Can a $0^{\circ}$ angle and a $180^{\circ}$ angle be considered supplementary?

Tags: geometry

I was talking to my friend yesterday and I said that a $0^{\circ}$ angle and a $180^{\circ}$ angle were supplementary but he said that that doesn't count. I tried searching different forums but wasn't able to find anything concrete and the exact definition for supplementary angles usually seemed to be something along the lines of "two angles that add up to 180 degrees" which fits with a $0^{\circ}$ angle and a $180^{\circ}$ angle.

Comment: I think that I would consider this pair of angles to be supplementary.  Perhaps you can include some of the context of your discussion to understand why this choice might not count.

Comment: Likewise, a $0^{\circ}$ and a $90^{\circ}$ angle are complementary.

Comment: Elementary contexts avoid discussing the zero angle *at all* so as not to have to deal with, say, "degenerate" triangles. Once $0^\circ$ enters discussion (typically w/introductory trig), "supplementary" reasonably applies to $0^\circ$ & $180^\circ$ as a pair. But then, around this same time, *signed* angles appear, inviting debate over whether, say, $-20^\circ$ and $200^\circ$ should count as "supplementary", which *really* starts stretching the original intent of the descriptor. But at that level, it's common enough to write "$180^\circ-x$" that "supplement of $x$" sees less usage, anyway.

Comment: All that said, it's worth keeping in mind that mathematicians can't even agree on [whether zero is a natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number), so opinions are likely to differ on how broadly to apply *any* given definition. Context matters. ... When it comes to mathematical terminology, this quote from [Lewis Carroll's *Through the Looking Glass*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty#Lewis_Carroll's_Through_the_Looking-Glass) applies: "When *I* use a word," Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, "it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less."

Comment: Thank you, everyone! For the people who wanted more context, we were talking about diet supplements, and I jokingly told my friend that you could technically supplement your diet with only pills, to which he replied that it's not "supplementing" at that point and made an analogy to a 180 angle and a 0-degree angle, sparking our debate.